# "2+2=5" Python edition

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can somebody explain this tricky output:

```
>>> not(type(1.01)) == type(1) # Why does the expression evaluates to True!?
True
>>> not(type(1.01))
False
>>> False == type(1)
False
```

What happens there? And why this happens?

**Answer:**
When I asked question I treated `not` as a function, but actually `not` isn't a function. That's why not(#something) doesn't change operator precedence. For example:

```
not(type(1.01)) == type(1)
```

is the same as:

```
not(type(1.01) == type(1))
```

and:

`not type(1.01) == type(1)`

but not the same as:

```
(not type(1.01)) == type(1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actully you considered not as a built-in functions and use not(..) as calling a function.  Infact for python not is a built-in Types. so add () would not change the result. these are some reference from python doc 2.7.5 and 3.2:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html
http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/boolean.html

they both say:
not has a lower priority than non-Boolean operators, so not a == b is interpreted as not (a == b), and a == not b is a syntax error.
which as exactly the answer of your question.

Answer (score 11):

Python is parsing

```
not(type(1.01)) == type(1)
```

as

```
not ((type(1.01)) == type(1))
```

(Note carefully the parentheses.)

The [operator precedence table](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) shows `not` has less precedence than `==`. So the `==` operator is causing `type(1.01) == type(1)` to be evaluated before the `not` is applied.

---

Here is another way to see how the expression is evaluated:

```
In [16]: type(1.01)
Out[16]: float

In [17]: type(1)
Out[17]: int

In [18]: float == int
Out[18]: False

In [19]: not float == int   # This is same as `not (float == int)`
Out[19]: True

In [20]: not (float) == int    
Out[20]: True

In [21]: not (type(1.01)) == int
Out[21]: True

In [22]: not (type(1.01)) == type(1)
Out[22]: True
```

Comment: But why this happens? You just repeat my question

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> not type(1.01) == type(1)
```

means  in psedocode

```
if 'float'is not a 'int':
      then print True
```

*so it'd print True* as a float is actually not a int

---

In the second example:

```
bool(type(1.01)) 
# True
```

*The `not` operator produces the opposite result*, Therefore since opposite of `True` is `False`, It produces `False`

```
not type(1.01) 
# False
```

---

In the third example:

```
bool(type(1))
#True
False == type(1)
#False
```

Since `True` is not equal to `False` it produces `False`